# How to extract date in yyyy-yyyy format using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I know this is basic but can someone please provide  a regex solution to extract "1234-5678" out of "abcfd1234-5678gfvjh". Here the leading and trailing strings can be anything and they might not be there always i.e. the string can be just "1234-5678" as well. It is guaranteed that there will no be alphabet between the numbers only "-" can be there. There is one more format of the string "1234-56". i.e. the second number can be of length 2 or 4. Please see the below explanation:

```
input  :a = "abcfd1234-5678gfvjh"

output :"1234-5678"

input  :a = "abcfd1234-56gfvjh"

output :"1234-56"

input  :a = "1234-5678hgjg"

output :"1234-5678"

input  :a = "abcfd1234-5678"

output :"1234-5678"

input  :a = "1234-56"

output :"1234-56"
```

Comment: What kind of date format is dddd-dddd supposed to be?

Comment: @ user2357112 edited my question...changed it to 'yyyy-yyyy' format.actually it is a year duration format.

Answer (score 1):

```
\d{4}[-–](?:\d{4}|\d{2})
```

See an explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/kocRuY/2

Basically we say to search for four digits then a hyphen then *either* (using a non-capturing group to bracket) four digits *or*, failing that, two digits.

You should use the regex "search" method rather than "match" method as the processor will have to find where the sequence starts in the string. If you are restricted to matching from the start with "match", then you could add some sort of quantifier at the start to gobble up the start characters.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I tried your method but it doesn't works for a = "1482–1484"

Comment: @aman That is because you are using a longer dash, rather than a hyphen, so matching a hyphen failed. I have updated the regex to match either a hyphen or a dash using a character set. This now works for your example (see the regex101 link for confirmation). If you need to support other variations on dashes/hyphens then just add them to the character set.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I cannot believe how I can be so stupid and not notice the difference between the real hyphen and the one given in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\d+-\d+', "abcfd1234-5678gfvjh")
['1234-5678']
```

you can try different regexes in https://regex101.com/

Comment: @ ishefi Thanks for quick response,I tried your method but it doesn't works for a = "1482–1484"

Comment: this is a different hyphen... just add it to the regex.

You can test and learn about regexes in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a dozen duplicates on `StackOverflow`.
As the request occurs very often, there's a module called [**`datefinder`**](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder) (`pip install datefinder`). You'd then call it like this:

```
import datefinder
matches = datefinder.find_dates(your_string_here)
for match in matches:
    print (match)
```

Comment: actually this method is not very efficient. In my case when I give the input as "1917–1918" it gave me the following output :' 1917-05-04 00:00:00' and 
'1918-05-04 00:00:00' which is not what I was expecting. A lot of reformatting needs  to be done on the output for me to use it.  Also when I give the input as  "1917–18" it doesn't works. Thanks for you response though. @Jan